Sequence numbers in QuickFixJ are not maintained properly without using ResetOn tags
Here is the quickfixj-client.cfg
[default]
FileStorePath=storage
ConnectionType=initiator
SenderCompID=
TargetCompID=
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
FileLogPath=logs


UseDataDictionary=Y
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=fix/CUSTOM_FIX50SP1.xml
#ResetOnDisconnect=Y
CheckLatency=N
RefreshOnLogon=Y


#ResetOnLogon=Y
#ResetOnLogout=Y
EnableNextExpectedMsgSeqNum=Y
PersistMessages=Y
TimeZone=
StartTime=
EndTime=
Weekdays=


[session]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP1
SocketConnectHost
SocketConnectPort=
SocketConnectHost1=
SocketConnectPort1=
LogonTag=553=
LogonTag1=554=


[session]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP1
SocketConnectHost=
SocketConnectPort=
SocketConnectHost1=
SocketConnectPort1=
LogonTag=553=
LogonTag1=554=

When the ResetOnLogon tag is on, the system works fine until it is disconnected or restarted and the logon message is interchanged (in between start time and end time). As the sequence number is reset from 1, some messages from the other side are missed. The case is the same with ResetOnLogout and ResetOnDisconnect and RefreshOnLogon tags.
When the ResetOn tags are set to N, then connection is hampered in three ways:
If the sender seq number is higher, then the target sends a resend request (35=2) and the sender side sends the missed messages and also sequence reset message (35=4). But then there is no response from the other side. So, the sender seq number keeps increasing and the target seq number is the same.
If the target seq number is higher, the sender keeps sending logout messages (35=5) until the sequence numbers are matched again whereas it should have sent a resend request.
At the beginning of the session (the first logon of the day), the target seq number in the file is null, so the sender seq number is increased after the logon and the target number remains null and thus no communication happens.
What are the reasons for this behavior and how to fix this? Thanks in advance.
I want the sequence number to be maintained without using any ResetOn tags, tried to change the configuration file but it is not working.

A message log would be helpful.

I want the sequence number to be maintained without using any ResetOn tags [...]. Is what "you want" based on how the counterparty is behaving? These flags should be set or unset depending on how the counterparty works, or on how you agreed the sequence numbering to take place.

According to the counter party, no ResetOn tags are used, but if I don't use it, the mentioned problems occur.

You will need to include relevant message logs in your question. It is hard to speculate without them.

Here is the log after a logon, the sender seq number file keeps updating but the target seq number file is empty
fromAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1 9=_ 35=A 34=1 49=_ 52=_ 56=_ 98=_ 108=_ 553=_ 554=_ 789=_ 1137=_ 10=_ , SessionId=FIXT.1.1:_
onLogon: SessionId=FIXT.1.1:_
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1 9=_ 35=0 34=1 49=_ 52=_ 56=_ 10=_ , SessionId=FIXT.1.1:_
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1 9=_ 35=0 34=2 49=_ 52=_ 56=_ 10=_ , SessionId=FIXT.1.1:_
toAdmin: Message=8=FIXT.1.1 9=_ 35=0 34=3 49=_ 52=_ 56=_ 10=_ , SessionId=FIXT.1.1:_

Which QFJ version are you using BTW? But the connection is working in general? The log looks ok to me.
